# How to speed up to read

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki, apache-jena

I'm starting to use [Apache Jena Fuseki](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) for running SPARQL in local.

I'm looking for a way to speed up to load an RDF file. 
Currently I'm using the following command as noted in the instruction.

```
s-put http://localhost:3030/ds/data default data.ttl
```

Since my RDF data is large (70GB), I would like to speed up loading data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDB has a number of [command line utilities](http://TDB%20Command-line%20Utilities) that you can use for getting data into the datastore.  In this case, you'd probably want to use **tdbloader** or the more efficient (but less portable) **tdbloader2.**

> #### [tdbloader](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader)
>
> Bulk loader and index builder. Performans [sic] bulk load operations more
>   efficiently than simply reading RDF into a TDB-back [sic] model.
>
> #### [tdbloader2](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/commands.html#tdbloader2)
>
> Bulk loader and index builder. Faster than **tdbloader** but only works on
>   Linux and Mac OS/X since it relies on some Unix system utilities.

Comment: see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Get_your_own_copy_of_WikiData#Test_with_Apache_Jena for some performance tests with tdbloader2 loading some 600 GB of WikiData triples